# Which app triggered the location update I received passively?

Tags: android, location

This might be considered as sensitive by the Android SDK, but I'd like to know if—when subscribing to passive location updates—there is a programmable way to capture the name (*e.g.*, package) of the Android app which triggered the location request?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "when subscribing to passive location updates...the Android app which triggered the location request?". Code sample for "subscribing passive location updates" would be best.

Comment: By passive subscription, I mean receiving location updates that are not triggered by my app. This typically refers to the following invocation: 
manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, requestTime, 0f, listener)